# Configuring BT support in Linux (Android)

Tags: linux, android, bluetooth

I'm trying bring up Bluetooth over USB support on a new ARM-based Android device. I think I'm missing some magic piece of configuration in order to successfully open a BT socket connection.

- BT is provided through a USB dongle (vs. UART in most Android devices)
- I can successfully run "hcitool scan" to discover devices.
- I can open a socket via libbluetooth in C
- When I try to establish an RFCOMM connection the connection, the connection
  is refused because an L2CAP connection cannot be established.

Also,

- for some OS's, I'm required to approve a pairing. (Older Ubuntu, some flavors of Windows' BT stack.)
- the peripheral device doesn't require a PIN, but in some cases I'm requested to provide one. (Windows has asked for this. Older version of Ubuntu has asked for this. It may also be when using BT 2.0 dongles, vs. BT 2.1 and up?).
- Bluetooth provided with Ubuntu 10 on my PC requires neither PIN nor pairing.

Am I missing a piece of config that says, i) auto-pair devices, ii) don't request a PIN if none is required?

Is there a guide to this online? Documentation seems limited.

Comment: I can say for sure that you are in the wrong place.  But I'm not sure if StackOverflow or SuperUser is the right place for this question.  I'm kicking the question to SO, but they may feel like SU is the right place.

Comment: "Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users". "Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers." "Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support professionals".